# Bootstrap v2.3.3 Navbar gets overlapped by Collapse content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue on my site where I have a bootstrap (version 2.3.2) `navbar` fixed to the top of the page and then later in the body I have a bootstrap `collapse` object with a large amount of content in `<pre><code>` tags. The `collapse` opens and closes as expected; however, when I scroll down the page, the content in the `<pre><code>` tags overlaps the `navbar` at the top of the page. I have **attempted** to add  `z-index`'s to both the `navbar` and the `collapse` content; however, it doesn't seem to be working.

Below are the jsfiddle links. The offending overlapping content is at the end of the page. Thanks!
 
My code: http://jsfiddle.net/K3JAe/3/ 
Full Screen Result: http://jsfiddle.net/K3JAe/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.collapse` class has `position: relative`, making it a positioned element, and your navbar has `position: fixed` from the Affix plugin, making it also positioned. The accordion comes later in the DOM, which makes it stack on the navbar.

@Adrift's fix is the way to go: the affixed element at the top of the page needs a `z-index` to stack on any later positioned elements. I would go higher than `2` though for your future z-indexing uses:

```
/* Stack .affix on top of positioned elements later in the DOM */
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `z-index` value to the `.affix` class above 1 seems to do the trick:

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3JAe/5/